# assigning first variable of struct to another

Tags: arrays, c, struct, char, initialization

I have *struct point* which has two variables and I don't know how to assign string from one to another. I'm not yet familiar with pointers, so I don't know if they should be used.

```
struct point
{
    int a, b;
    char name[5];
} A = {3, 5, "plane"}, B;

int main(){
    struct point B = {A.a, A.b, A.name};
    printf("%d %d %s", B.a, B.b, B.name);
}
```

Output is: 3 5 ♀. How do I assign string of A to B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as to declare a string in C you must consider that the last element is always `\0` (it is the `NULL` ascii char) so as to contain "plane" your array shoud be large lengh of "plane"+1 (6, `{'p','l','a','n','e','\0'}`).

---

**If you want to use pointers:**

Just declare `B` as a struct point pointer (*B) and then point it to `A` so as to print the values of A you just need to point `B` to them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point
{
    int a, b;
    char name[6];
} A = {3, 5, "plane"}, *B;

int main(){
    //struct point B = {A.a, A.b, A.name};
    B = &A;
    printf("%d %d %s", B->a, B->b, B->name);
}
```

---

**Without pointers:**

You have only to replace `struct point B = {A.a, A.b, A.name};` with `B = A;`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point
{
    int a, b;
    char name[6];
} A = {3, 5, "plane"}, B;

int main(){
    //struct point B = {A.a, A.b, A.name};
    B = A;
    printf("%d %d %s", B.a, B.b, B.name);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I had noticed my error and corrected it in a previous reply edit, but I don't understand why it didn't show up. I apologize for the error anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I got this warning when I ran this program

> main.c:12:34: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
> main.c:12:34: note: (near initialization for ‘B.name[0]’)

you cannot assign address to an array, declare `name` as a pointer or use `strcpy` as shown below.

Also your array `name` should have a space for `\0`, so declare it as `char name[6];`

```
int main(){
    struct point B =  {A.a, A.b};//, A.name};
    
    strcpy(B.name,A.name);
    
    printf("%d %d %s", B.a, B.b, B.name);
}
```

Comment: It is a warning not an error, according to compiler.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula, you are right of course, its a warning which will have impact on the output, I will correct the wording.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an array of 5 characters is one to less to hold a string `"plane"`. You need an array with 6 chars (one for null terminator). Without that null terminator in place, when the variable is supplied as argument to `%s` conversion specifier, out of bound access will happen (in search of the null terminator), which will cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change

```
char name[5];
```

to

```
char name[6];
```

if you intend to use `name` as a *string*.

That said, to copy one structure variable values to another variable of the same type, you just need to use assignment operator `=`, like

```
 struct point B = A;
```

Comment: warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   17 |     struct point B = {A.a, A.b, A.name};
      |                                                 ^

Right, I forgot about \0, but there's still error.

Comment: @qu4lizz That's because assignment to array type. I updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that in this declaration

```
struct point B = {A.a, A.b, A.name};
```

the last initializer `A.name` has the pointer type `char *` that is used to initialize a character array. You may not initialize an array with a pointer.

You could just write

```
struct point B = A;
```

Take into account that due to this initialization

```
struct point
{
    int a, b;
    char name[5];
} A = {3, 5, "plane"}, B;
```

the character array `A.name` is not contain a string because there is no space in the array for the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literal.

As a result you may not use the format string `%s` in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d %d %s", B.a, B.b, B.name);
```

Instead you can write

```
printf("%d %d %.*s", B.a, B.b, ( int )sizeof( B.name ), B.name);
```

That is your program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point
{
    int a, b;
    char name[5];
} A = {3, 5, "plane"}, B;

int main( void ){
    struct point B = A;
    printf("%d %d %.*s", B.a, B.b, ( int )sizeof( B.name ),B.name);
}
```

If you want that the character array `name` would contain a string then you need to enlarge its size at least by one more character like

```
struct point
{
    int a, b;
    char name[6];
} A = {3, 5, "plane"}, B;
```

In this case you may use the following call of `printf`

```
printf("%d %d %s", B.a, B.b, B.name);
```